# can't select multiple tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I am unable to select multiple tabs in Chrome by either the ctrl- or shift-click. Is this feature not supported on Linux? Is there a way to enable it? Thanks

Comment: I think this feature is Windows and Mac only.

Comment: I don't know for Chrome, but this feature works as it is expected within Chromium. Why you don't use it? 

**Chromium browser** offers exactly the same user's feature as Google Chrome, but it is: optimized for Linux, works (start|stop) much faster, the application window looks better (there is no an additional border), it is available from the official repositories. Yes if has [few cons](https://www.howtogeek.com/202825/what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-chromium-and-chrome/), but in most cases I do not feel some sensitive lack of them...

Comment: Feature works in Google Chrome as well as in Chromium. I tested it now. I don't know, where the problem is. Maybe you should update package to latest release and try it again?

Comment: @pa4080 thanks. Does it support logging in to the Google account and syncing bookmarks and browsing data?

Comment: Yes it does. Just try it :) The only major lack is Adobe Flash support, so if you want to play online games Chrome is better.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that selecting multiple tabs works with the default theme and does not work with the GTK and QT themes. So, to make it work, switch to the default theme in Settings, Appearance, Theme (or what; my Chromium is not in English, so I translated the menu items to English). This is in Chromium 119.

Edit: Selecting multiple tabs in the GTK and QT themes actually works, but it isn't shown. If you have such theme and select multiple tabs holding Shift, you can move them together, but it is not apparent that they are selected.